# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 2):

Just a few days left - RandomBen and I have nominated ourselves... are any of the other Pro Tem moderation team members running?

Comment: What is Pro Tem?

Comment: Pro Tem mods are temporary mods who volunteered to moderate until elections could be held. I'm a pro tem mod and am undecided about running. I have enough rep to act have access to mod tools anyway so maybe we're better off with someone else becoming a mod instead.

Comment: I'm not running.  It's been interesting, but haven't been able to devote the time I think it deserves.